# Why is my UPDATE statement taking a long time to affect only 242 rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
begin try
    begin tran
        update i
        set i.Uf_Commodity = t.commodity
        from item i inner join #temp1 t on i.item = t.item
    commit tran
end try

begin catch
    if (xact_state() = 1 or xact_state() = -1) and @@trancount > 1
    begin   

        rollback tran
        print('Transaction rolled back.')

    end

end catch
```

I populated a temp table called `#temp1` with items and commodity values. I now need to update the `item` table with all of these commodities. For some reason, when I execute this the query keeps running for an unusually long time (I stopped it after 15 seconds, it shouldn't take this long). This UPDATE should take only a second. Did I make a mistake when writing the statement?

Comment: How many rows in the  item table? Is item unique? Check the execution plan to make sure the index on item is being used, assuming one exists.

Comment: Can you check to see if there are any triggers on the item table?  Triggers, if not done properly, can account for poor performance.

Comment: 14561 rows in the item table. The `item` is unique in both the `item` and `#temp1` tables.

Comment: Yes, there are triggers on the `item` table.

Comment: what those triggers are doing? You may want to check execution plan to know where is it blocking?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
update i
    set i.Uf_Commodity = t.commodity
    from item i inner join
         #temp1 t
         on i.item = t.item;
```

I would suggest an index on `#temp1(item, commodity)`.  You probably already have an index on `i(item)`.

Comment: Is that really the only issue here? If I run a select statement JOINing both tables, it takes less than one second to execute. Seems strange to have an update statement take much much longer.

Comment: You might have outstanding locks on the table that are preventing the update.